# How to change custom attribute of table cell when event was caused by object inside that cell - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have a table with input text in it, here is an example:

```
<table>
<tr><td customattribute="1"><input type='text' onchange='somefunction();'></td></tr>
<tr><td customattribute="2"><input type='text' onchange='somefunction();'></td></tr>
</table>
```

I have a function:

```
var myInput = something that would target td cell that is containing input causing onchange event
myInput.setAttribute('customattribute', $(this).val());
```

I want to change customattrubute of td that contains input that caused event to inputs value. How can I do that without assigning id's to those elements.
how do i set myInput  to "td cell that is containing input causing onchange event"

I understand I should use some combination of $(this) and perhaps $(this).find ?

Comment: I would investigate parent()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the `<td>`, use the `.parent()` function. However, since you are using HTML function, you will have to pass `this` to the function. Try this:

```js
function somefunction(myInputBox){
  var myInput = $(myInputBox).parent()[0];
  myInput.setAttribute('customattribute', $(myInputBox).val());
  //this line is just for testing.
  alert(myInput.attributes['customattribute'].value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td customattribute="1"><input type='text' onchange='somefunction(this);'></td></tr>
<tr><td customattribute="2"><input type='text' onchange='somefunction(this);'></td></tr>
</table>
```

You can also use the jQuery `myInput.attr()` instead of the `myInput.setAttribute()`, so you don't have to use the `[0]` at the end of `parent()`. (see below).

Alternatively, you can bind the `click` event using jQuery instead of in HTML `onchange='somefunction();'`. This way you don't have to pass `this`. I personally prefer the HTML unless I need to bind it at run time for some reason. Anyway, it's up to you:

```js
$("input").change(function() {
  var myInput = $(this).parent();
  myInput.attr('customattribute', $(this).val());
  alert(myInput.attr('customattribute'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td customattribute="1"><input type='text'></td></tr>
<tr><td customattribute="2"><input type='text'></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "Parent" was a keyword I was missing. Your code works great thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the combination between .change() and .parent() to do it

This is the code

http://jsfiddle.net/mankinchi/m4g9czc4/1/

You use

```
$("input").change();
```

to set an event for every input. And use

```
$(this).parent();
```

to get the container